# send a bitmap image path but have null error

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I send the path of image that user choose from galley and send it to view class i think it get the path but when i want to set the bitmap in image view the app crashes.and i don't know why its happening
:
this is my send code:

```
public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            CanvasView c =new CanvasView(this);
            c.setCanvasPath(picturePath); //this send
        }
```

and one the other hand in my View class:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    Canvas drawCanvas;
    public CanvasView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public void setCanvasPath(String bitmap_path) {
        Log.e("logiiiiiiiiin",bitmap_path);
        BitmapFactory.Options decode_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        decode_options.inMutable = true;
        canvasBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmap_path,decode_options);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
}
```

and this is my log:

```
03-27 22:57:24.573    8941-8941/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-27 22:57:46.123    8941-8941/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/logiiiiiiiiin﹕ /storage/sdcard0/viber/media/Viber Images/image-d89aac5f0af482a6fe466f1cd32f9836d51cd6d30326b25a377a8b213cab72b8-V.jpg
03-27 22:57:46.253    8941-8941/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.htc.HTCAlbum.action.ITEM_PICKER_FROM_COLLECTIONS dat=content: typ=image/jpeg (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3660)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3710)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.CanvasView.setCanvasPath(CanvasView.java:28)
            at com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test.second.onActivityResult(second.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3656)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3710)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 22:59:49.043  10261-10261/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-27 23:00:05.423  10261-10261/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/logiiiiiiiiin﹕ /storage/sdcard0/viber/media/Viber Images/image-d89aac5f0af482a6fe466f1cd32f9836d51cd6d30326b25a377a8b213cab72b8-V.jpg
03-27 23:00:56.163  11670-11670/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-27 23:01:06.133  11670-11670/com.example.pooyafayyaz.first_photo_edit_test E/logiiiiiiiiin﹕ /storage/sdcard0/viber/media/Viber Images/image-d89aac5f0af482a6fe466f1cd32f9836d51cd6d30326b25a377a8b213cab72b8-V.jpg
```

Comment: The problem is "/storage/sdcard0/viber/media/Viber Images/image-d89aac5f0af482a6fe466f1cd32f9836d51cd6d30326b25a377a8b213cab72b8-V.jpg" this path.The photo is either corrupted or path isn't correct.

Comment: @Soham no.if i set this path in image view before send it,it shows correctly.

Comment: From your log: What is on line 28 of CanvasView.java ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure, but exactly which line is the null pointer happening? Is it imageView? If so, you're view has probably not been inflated yet.